(distributed) DataLoader when batches are correlated, pitfals?
I know how to implement Datasets and Dataloaders in pytorch.
However, when it comes to distributed and correlated batch generation, I need advise.
Background
I have a network that generates a new state along with the output. This new state is combined with the next data sample from the sequence to form the next input.
Pseudocode
# 1. Generate B initial zero states
states = torch.zero((B,C))

# 2. Fetch B initial frames from B different video sequences
batch = next(...)

# 3. iterate over n_frames
for i in range(n_frames)
  model(states, batch) = states, outputs
  # fetch frame i+1 for each video used in the current batch
  batch = next(...)

Are there any pitfalls in a DDP setting? Are batches indeed generated independently for each GPU or can it happen that frame_0 ends up at rank 0 while frame_1 of the same sequence is processed on rank 3? This would be hard to debug, I guess.
If sequence lengths differ between batches, what would be a good approach to ensure that each GPU receives a batch of similar length to avoid idle time? How can the independent(?) DataLoaders communicate this? I did not find a good starting point yet in the pytorch code, maybe you can point me in the right direction.
